# Broke Spokes backwheel e bike

Tags: spokes, electric-bike, rear-wheel

Four spokes on backwheel of Riverside 500 ebike just snapped when I was going uphill. Anyone else had this problem or know why it could have happened?

Comment: We have several similar questins and answers. Wrong spoke tension will be a common theme in all of them. It is the time to have the wheel re-laced.

Comment: Did you hear a metallic "tink-tink-tink" sound before it went bad ?  That's the rear derailleur hitting spokes and is your warning to stop and fix it.   Check your mech and make sure its not bent, or the hanger.    Did the spokes break at the J bend or the nipple end ?

Comment: And do browse the linked questions on the right hand side under "RELATED"  there are multiple relevant pre-existing questions about spokes and breakage.

Comment: Yeah Criggie, I heard a noise but he derailler wasn'"t in the spokes, one broke at the nipple and the other three at the hub. New on the site so I'll check the other answers